# Why method updateApplicationContext returns "Payload contains unsupported type."

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I am calling method:

```
 open func updateApplicationContext(_ applicationContext: [String : Any]) throws
```

That takes `[String : Any]`.

I have method that returns :

```
 func watchData() -> [String: Any] {
        var dictionary = [String: Any]()
        let wallets = Database.sharedInstance.database.objects(Wallet.self)
        for wallet in wallets {
            if let qrCode = QRCode(wallet.address) {
                 let watchWallet = WatchWallet(fund: wallet.fund, avaliable: wallet.avaliable, address: wallet.address, imageData: qrCode.PNGData)
                  dictionary[wallet.fund] = watchWallet
            }
        }
        return dictionary
    }
```

And data that is returned from `watchData()` is not valid.

`WatchWallet` is strcut.

```
struct WatchWallet {
    let fund: String
    let avaliable: String
    let address: String
    let imageData: Data
}
```

I am wondering what i am missing.

Error from the method:

**Unable to send application context: Error Domain=WCErrorDomain Code=7010 "Payload contains unsupported type." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Payload contains unsupported type., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Only pass valid types.}**

Comment: @jlew thx for the suggestion but error is same

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/SharingData.html

> For most types of transfers, you provide an NSDictionary object with
>   the data you want to send. The keys and values of your dictionary must
>   all be property list types, because the data must be serialized and
>   sent wirelessly. (If you need to include types that are not property
>   list types, package them in an NSData object or write them to a file
>   before sending them.)

So, the fact that the dictionary is `[String: Any]` is misleading, because the `Any` values are restricted to valid property list types. The full list of types is in the article below, but as you might expect) include primitive types, arrays, dictionaries, and NSData:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html

Comment: So my struct should use only data types that are in the list belove ?

Comment: Not exactly.  The dictionary must not contain a `WatchWallet` as a value.  You should instead convert it to a dictionary and put that in the `WatchWallet`'s place: 
`dictionary[wallet.fund] = ["fund": wallet.fund, "available": wallet.available, ..etc...]`